# Dictionary of lists that include either all even or all odd combinations of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary of either all even or all odd combinations of integers. 
My code so far:

```
values = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]] 

combos = np.array([list(i) for i in np.array(np.meshgrid(*values)).T.reshape(-1,len(values))])

print(combos)
```

This takes three lists that each contain the integers 0-2

and uses an element from each list to create a combination of three integers

All possible combinations are printed: [0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,2,0], [1,0,0] ... [2,2,2]

I am trying to discard all the results that do not contain either all odd or all even numbers.

I would like the remaining results to be in a dictionary
(for example I want to keep [0,0,0] and [0,2,0] but discard [0,1,0])

So far I have these ideas but not sure where to go from there:

```
r=combos%2  #remainder after dividing everything by 2
keep= np.all(r==0) and np.all(r==1)
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: `I want to keep [0,0,0] and [0,2,0]` they are not all odd or even. Did you mean you want to discard [0,2,0]?

Comment: @KapishM I guess he is considering 0 to be even in that example and he would be keeping [0,2,0] as all even

Comment: Yes, I am taking 0 to be an even number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about what you mean by having the remaining results in a dictionary but according to your code snippet, you seem to be looking for a boolean array indicating which rows of your 2d array to keep.

`r = combos % 2`

This indicates for every single number in the array if it is odd or even.

To get the indices of the rows to keep, you need to consider two cases:

1. All numbers in the row are even
2. All numbers in the row are odd

Using `np.all` will check the whole array and not just the current row. So you need to pass the parameter `axis=1` to apply the function not along the whole array but only along the columns.

Consequently, to check if all entries in the row are odd, you can do

```py
r.all(axis=1)
```

To check if a row contains only even numbers, none of the remainders may be one. So what you need here is not `np.all` but `~.np.any`.

```py
~r.any(axis=1)
```

Now, since you want to keep all rows the are either all even or all odd, you can use the logical OR.

```py
keep = r.all(axis=1) | ~r.any(axis=1)
```

You can then filter your original array like this:

```py
filtered = combos[keep]
```

Now regarding the dictionary part, you need to clarify a bit more what you mean.

edited: In case you want to have a dictionary with the keys "even" and "odd", you can do this:

```py
result_dict = {
    "odd": combos[r.all(axis=1)].tolist(),
    "even": combos[~r.any(axis=1)].tolist()
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant way of doing it and solves my problem perfectly!
Thank you so much for your help.

I didn't want to over complicate the above problem, but my next step is to find the sum of the squares of the three values for all allowed combinations. These numerical values are the values I need to store in a dictionary (with the key being which three numbers the value came from)

Comment: Also this might be a very novice question to ask, but the output combinations aren't separated by commas. I was just wondering how this would affect the result from further manipulation if the values aren't separated as such?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
values = [[2,2,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[3,3,3],[1,1,1]]
combo = []
for i in values:
        status = 0
        for x in i:
                if x%2 == 0:
        #               status = 0
        #               print(x%2)
                        pass
                else:
                        status += 1
        if status ==3:
                combo.append(i)
        if status ==0:
                combo.append(i)

print (combo)
```

output -

```
[[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: This worked great when I tried it out, thank you so much! May I ask what exactly 'if status ==3:' and 'if status ==0:' part does exactly?

Comment: `3` is when all items are odd. `0` is when all items are even.

Comment: Ah I see! Each value in an even set has a value of one, which results in a total of 3 and each value in an odd set has a value of 0 for a total of 0